# Networking on MainThread Appcompat v7

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-networking, android-appcompat

I'm having a problem with `Appcompat v7` and networking on mainthread.

I do know that it's not possible from `API level 11`. Right now, i have `API level 10` as minimun, and `API level 14` as target.

The application works correctly on my device with **2.3.6**, but won't work on the device with **4.4**

How can i fix this problem without changing the networking code?

Comment: change the networking code. it is not a matter of the minSdk, or targetSdk, it is only a matter of the device's version.

Comment: Oh, so it won't work anyway?

Comment: you could always force it (search networkonmainthreadexception), but your users will hate you for it. (if you server does not respond, your app is basically stuck)

Comment: @njzk2 - No, that is not the case, it is governed by the target SDK not the device version - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html However I agree that changing the networking code is the proper solution as the checks were put there for a good reason.